# Compile imagemagick for android

Tags: android, compilation, imagemagick

I am trying to compile this project https://github.com/lilac/Android-ImageMagick.
To produce the android-magick.so I need to compile it on my system.
I have modified the rebuild script and become the following errors.

```
Clean: MagickCore [armeabi]
Clean: android-magick [armeabi]
Clean: coders [armeabi]
Clean: filters [armeabi]
Clean: jpeg [armeabi]
Clean: stdc++ [armeabi]
Clean: tiff-shared [armeabi]
Clean: tiff-static [armeabi]
Clean: tiffinfo [armeabi]
Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3] libs/armeabi/gdbserver
Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
Compile thumb  : android-magick <= jmagick.c
/home/vita/projects/lilac-Android-ImageMagick-5f1c8b5/jni/jmagick.c:7:24: error: magick/api.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /home/vita/projects/lilac-Android-ImageMagick-5f1c8b5/jni/jmagick.c:8:
/home/vita/projects/lilac-Android-ImageMagick-5f1c8b5/jni/jmagick.h:4:26: error: magick/image.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /home/vita/projects/lilac-Android-ImageMagick-5f1c8b5/jni/jmagick.c:8:
/home/vita/projects/lilac-Android-ImageMagick-5f1c8b5/jni/jmagick.h:26: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '*' token
/home/vita/projects/lilac-Android-ImageMagick-5f1c8b5/jni/jmagick.h:131: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'RectangleInfo'
/home/vita/projects/lilac-Android-ImageMagick-5f1c8b5/jni/jmagick.h:151: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'PixelPacket'
/home/vita/projects/lilac-Android-ImageMagick-5f1c8b5/jni/jmagick.h:165: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'Image'
/home/vita/projects/lilac-Android-ImageMagick-5f1c8b5/jni/jmagick.h:198: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'ProfileInfo'
/home/vita/projects/lilac-Android-ImageMagick-5f1c8b5/jni/jmagick.h:212: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'ProfileInfo'
/home/vita/projects/lilac-Android-ImageMagick-5f1c8b5/jni/jmagick.c:38: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '*' token
/home/vita/projects/lilac-Android-ImageMagick-5f1c8b5/jni/jmagick.c: In function 'getHandle':
/home/vita/projects/lilac-Android-ImageMagick-5f1c8b5/jni/jmagick.c:150: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
/home/vita/projects/lilac-Android-ImageMagick-5f1c8b5/jni/jmagick.c: In function 'setHandle':
/home/vita/projects/lilac-Android-ImageMagick-5f1c8b5/jni/jmagick.c:204: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size
/home/vita/projects/lilac-Android-ImageMagick-5f1c8b5/jni/jmagick.c: At top level:
/home/vita/projects/lilac-Android-ImageMagick-5f1c8b5/jni/jmagick.c:586: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'RectangleInfo'
/home/vita/projects/lilac-Android-ImageMagick-5f1c8b5/jni/jmagick.c: In function 'getRectangle':
/home/vita/projects/lilac-Android-ImageMagick-5f1c8b5/jni/jmagick.c:595: error: 'iRect' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/vita/projects/lilac-Android-ImageMagick-5f1c8b5/jni/jmagick.c:595: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
/home/vita/projects/lilac-Android-ImageMagick-5f1c8b5/jni/jmagick.c:595: error: for each function it appears in.)
/home/vita/projects/lilac-Android-ImageMagick-5f1c8b5/jni/jmagick.c: At top level:
/home/vita/projects/lilac-Android-ImageMagick-5f1c8b5/jni/jmagick.c:622: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'PixelPacket'
/home/vita/projects/lilac-Android-ImageMagick-5f1c8b5/jni/jmagick.c: In function 'getPixelPacket':
/home/vita/projects/lilac-Android-ImageMagick-5f1c8b5/jni/jmagick.c:637: error: 'iPixelPacket' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/vita/projects/lilac-Android-ImageMagick-5f1c8b5/jni/jmagick.c:637: error: 'Quantum' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/vita/projects/lilac-Android-ImageMagick-5f1c8b5/jni/jmagick.c:637: error: expected ';' before 'red'
/home/vita/projects/lilac-Android-ImageMagick-5f1c8b5/jni/jmagick.c:638: error: expected ';' before 'green'
/home/vita/projects/lilac-Android-ImageMagick-5f1c8b5/jni/jmagick.c:639: error: expected ';' before 'blue'
/home/vita/projects/lilac-Android-ImageMagick-5f1c8b5/jni/jmagick.c:640: error: expected ';' before 'opacity'
/home/vita/projects/lilac-Android-ImageMagick-5f1c8b5/jni/jmagick.c: At top level:
/home/vita/projects/lilac-Android-ImageMagick-5f1c8b5/jni/jmagick.c:662: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'Image'
/home/vita/projects/lilac-Android-ImageMagick-5f1c8b5/jni/jmagick.c: In function 'newImageObject':
/home/vita/projects/lilac-Android-ImageMagick-5f1c8b5/jni/jmagick.c:684: error: 'image' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/vita/projects/lilac-Android-ImageMagick-5f1c8b5/jni/jmagick.c: At top level:
/home/vita/projects/lilac-Android-ImageMagick-5f1c8b5/jni/jmagick.c:733: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'ProfileInfo'
/home/vita/projects/lilac-Android-ImageMagick-5f1c8b5/jni/jmagick.c: In function 'setProfileInfo':
/home/vita/projects/lilac-Android-ImageMagick-5f1c8b5/jni/jmagick.c:746: error: 'profileInfo' undeclared (first use in this function)
/home/vita/projects/lilac-Android-ImageMagick-5f1c8b5/jni/jmagick.c: At top level:
/home/vita/projects/lilac-Android-ImageMagick-5f1c8b5/jni/jmagick.c:768: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'ProfileInfo'
/home/vita/projects/lilac-Android-ImageMagick-5f1c8b5/jni/jmagick.c: In function 'getProfileInfo':
/home/vita/projects/lilac-Android-ImageMagick-5f1c8b5/jni/jmagick.c:795: error: 'profileInfo' undeclared (first use in this function)
make: *** [/home/vita/projects/lilac-Android-ImageMagick-5f1c8b5/obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/android-magick/jmagick.o] Fehler 1
```

Can somebody give me some hints?

Comment: I didnt found the solution, but if someone really need to compile it. Here you can find the compiled version of the libandroid-magick.so. https://github.com/lilac/Android-ImageMagick/blob/d28222850a95cac27477bafbc6c1b543ff6fd9cc/libs/armeabi/libandroid-magick.so. This is required to run the example.

Comment: Looks like your header files are missing - magick/api.h, etc. As to where to get them, double check the locations of all compiled and project files. Looks like it's expecting them in a dir called "magick" locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to manually go and change all the paths in the include lines to absolute paths. I had the same problem and fixed it that way.

So for example in jmagick.c, you'll have a line where it says
`include <magick/api.h>` or `include "magick/api.h"`
You'll have to change this to the absolute path of where the api.h file is. Mine was in C:/SomeFolders/Android-ImageMagick-master/Android-ImageMagick-master/ndk-modules/ImageMagick-6.7.3-0/magick so I changed my include directives to
`include <C:/SomeFolders/Android-ImageMagick-master/Android-ImageMagick-master/ndk-modules/ImageMagick-6.7.3-0/magick/api.h>`
And you'll have to do this in all the files that give you this "No such file or directory" error

Once I did these, though, it asked for an ft2build.h header file, which was actually nowhere on my disk. So I don't know what to do about that :(