# Is there a port of ImageMagick available for Android?

Tags: android, image-processing, android-ndk, imagemagick

I want to use the [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) as a library in an Android app.

I've tried [lilac's ImageMagick build](https://github.com/lilac/Android-ImageMagick) and also [looked at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832217/compile-imagemagick-for-android-using-ndk) but I was not able to build the library. I found a [solution to compiling the library here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899294/compile-imagemagick-for-android) but the demo application still didn't work - it exits with a blank screen both on android emulator and device as well ([device log](http://pastebin.com/bRJZgt9g)).

---

Have there been any ports of the ImageMagick library that work on Android?

Comment: How about posting the errors?

Comment: @biztiger Have you tried this port which is based on the lilac one? https://github.com/paulasiimwe/Android-ImageMagick. It's reasonably active with the latest commits being in 2016.